# Enumerate all Delphi classes that implement a given interface?

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-2010, rtti, delphi-xe

With the new extended RTTI in Delphi 2010, can a Delphi application (at run time) build a list of all classes which implement a given interface?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Technically yes, so long as the interface has a GUID and the classes you care about are in the interface sections of units.

The RTTI unit does not (yet) have an API for describing all interfaces that a class implements, but the data is in the type info.

The GUID for an interface type can be gotten from this expression:

```
GetTypeData(TypeInfo(ITheInterface))^.Guid
```

or:

```
ctx: TRttiContext;
// ...
(ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(ITheInterface)) as TRttiInterfaceType).GUID
```

The class of the instance type can then be checked using `TClass.GetInterfaceEntry(IID)` - if it returns non-nil, the class implements the interface.

All classes declared in interface sections of units can be retrieved via `TRttiContext.GetTypes`.

Writing the actual iteration and extraction code is left as an exercise for the reader.